# create a combobox that suggest and filter in Ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I'm working on access I create a combobox in a form that gives a liste of values recorded in a table . now I want that the combobox gives me a suggestion and filter in the same time.
For example : in the table I have johni , lika , mike .
so  when I type "ik" suggests lika,mike
and when I type "ika" suggests lika

Comment: I don't think you can filter the combobox directly.  What you can do is change the combobox rowsource and refresh it.  I would put a text box above the combobox  and use vba to filter the combobox rowsource

Comment: I use a rowsource a query builder , that gives me all records . but me  I want that the comobox gives me only records that contain a lettre when I type, I don't know how can I do this

Answer (score 0):

You can filter a combobox using a textbox.

[image]

[image]

the textbox afterchange event works best:

```
Private Sub filterTextBox_Change()
Dim comboboxrowsourcestring As String
comboboxrowsourcestring = "SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE ClientName like '*" & Me.filterTextBox.Text & "*'"

Me.ClientNameComboBox.RowSource = comboboxrowsourcestring
End Sub
```

1. Look up the like operator to change how the filter behaves.
2. the two ' in the comboboxrowsourcestring are important don't forget them.

Comment: good idea thank you  but it would be nice if a have only one filed instead of two (combobox+textbox)

Comment: Sorry I guess I never saw your comment.  You can get a lot closer to what you want by formating the controls to look and act as one.  Start the combobox as invisible beside the textbox.  as the user types into the textbox use the textbox on change event to show and update the combobox.