# Filter Combo box based on what's entered in text box in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

I have a form called Software which I'm trying to have filtered based on what is entered in the box. The form calls from another table called Software titles and pulls `title` from that list. It can either be a combo box or Text box but it would be nice if when you start typing if it could pull up the results as you type. I'd like to set it up to where the box shows results such as:

If `Vis` is entered it will only return results where `Title` starts with `Vis`.

I'm a beginner and mostly setup through SQL/Access interface. I have not dealt with VBA.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: "Find as you type" is a common topic. Start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172467/access-combo-filter-as-you-type

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810301/access-multi-field-search-with-results-as-you-type

Comment: I took a look at these but got a little lost...

Comment: Well, apparently 'find as you type' is not simple and I've never needed. So, for something simpler, review this other Allen Browne article http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: not exactly what you are looking for but might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896371/create-a-combobox-that-suggest-and-filter-in-ms-access/65896785#65896785

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Place a button named `Search` near the text box and add the following code to the click event:

```
Me.Form.Filter = "[title] Like '*" & [titleTextBox] & "*'"
Me.Form.FilterOn = True
```